# ResizeOffscreenFrameBuffer failed to allocate storage for offscreen

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to develop an Application in Android using PhoneGap .

This is my code

```
package com.example.streat;

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends DroidGap  {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.e("SOMESTRING", "I am into pGAP");
            super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.streat"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.streat.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>



<activity
    android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
    <intent-filter></intent-filter>
</activity>


</manifest>
```

when monitored inside the Logcat , i am getting this exception at the end

```
04-23 05:27:36.570: E/chromium(902): [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(3389)] GLES2DecoderImpl::ResizeOffscreenFrameBuffer failed to allocate storage for offscreen target depth buffer.

04-23 05:27:36.580: E/chromium(902): [ERROR:in_process_command_buffer.cc(465)] Could not initialize decoder.

04-23 05:27:36.590: A/libc(902): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000048 (code=1), thread 902 (.example.streat)
```

Could anybody please tell me how to resolve this error .
I have also tried to increase the size of the ram and heap , but nothing worked .

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like an issue in the GL/ES support. Disabling "`Use Host GPU`" emulation option in your AVD might help.